# Reasoning about Degree of Polynomial

Tags: kernel

Apologies if this is outside of the realm of Mathematica -- I'm still trying to figure out the limits of how expressive Mathematica is (and how much of my work can be automated).

Suppose I define the following:

```
f[1] = x
f[n_] = x * f[n-1]
```

Then, I want to ask:

```
for integral k>1, what is the degree of f[k] ?
```

so for example, I want to write a function:

```
degreeOf[f, k] = k
```

Now, I know that in this above example, given that we know how f is defined, it's trivial that degreeOf[f, k] = k. However, is it possible to write generic degreeOf ?

In a sense, I'm curious if the "computational" part of mathematica -- it's ability to handle symbols and do substitutions + simplifications -- or if it can reason about them at a deeper level.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you have defined your function recursively, you will first need to solve the recurrence equation using `RSolve` to get the general form.

For example:

```
F = f /. First @ RSolve[{f[n] == x f[n - 1], f[1] == x}, f, n]
(*  Function[{n}, x^n]  *)

Exponent[F[k], x]
(*  k  *)
```

Comment: This is amazing.

Answer (score 6):

Does [`Exponent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Exponent.html) do what you expect from `degreeOf[]`?

> [image]

```
 f = (x^3 + 1)^3 + 1;
 Exponent[f, x]
 (* ==> 9 *)
```

Comment: I did not explain my question well. The point is that I want to get Exponent[f[n], x] WITHOUT knowing n, i.e. I want a symbolic response back of "n".

Comment: @term-rewritica You mean as in Exponent[x^(n - 1) + x^a, x] (*=> Max[a,n-1]*)? Seems Exponent works fine in that case as well.

Comment: term-rewritica, similar to the example in @jVincent's comment, `f = (x^n + 1)^3 + 1; Exponent[f, x]` gives `Max[0, n, 2 n, 3 n]`.